# convert long binary data in database access to image using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

here is my code:

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    string query = "select * from StudentInformation where [StudentID] = " + txtStudentID.Text + "";
    command.CommandText = query;
    OleDbDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (read.Read())
    {
       txtStudentID.Text = (read["StudentID"].ToString());
       txtFirstname.Text = (read["Firstname"].ToString());
       txtLastname.Text = (read["Lastname"].ToString());

        byte[] imgbyte = (byte[])read["Image"];    //when i add this a got error with this code
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgbyte);
        StudentPicture.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }

    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

i get the error "Parameter is not valid" 
someone can help me?
im so confused!
i tried all the codes what i searched but still Error :'(
sorry for my bad english
Your response will be greatly appreciated....

Comment: 1) You should use parameterized queries so as to avoid SQL Injection.  2) "Parameter is not valid" means that the image data is bad.  What is the definition of the StudentInformation table?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting your byte array like this instead:

```
var binLength = read.Item[3].Length;
byte[] imgByte = new byte[binLength - 1];
var bytes = read.GetBytes(0,0,imgByte,0,imgByte.Length);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgByte);
StudentPicture.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: can't use .Item

Comment: @ClintJoe Why not?

Comment: Error 1 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @ClintJoe Sorry, was away for a while.  Also, sorry there is a bug in my example.  read.Item(3) should be read.Item[3].  I've fixed it in my answer.